# Application usable only via navigation bar (like the bottom appbar in windows or the top bar in macos)

Tags: linux, windows, macos

Is my first question on StackOverflow if i can improve my explaination skills please tell me.
I need to create an app that runs in background (better if multiplatfomr -> Windows, Mac, Linux). The only interaction that I want with the user is from the navigation bar of the operative system. Probably i don't know the exact term to search because I cannot find any suggestion about this via google.
My goal is to give an alert like antiviruses.
Best regards.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS, check out the documentation for [NSStatusBar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusbar?language=objc) and [NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem?language=objc).

There is also information about how to use these items in the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/status-bars/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).